# Installing Bootstrap 4 with bower

Tags: bower, yeoman, bootstrap-4, bower-install

I have generated a yeoman website and that comes along with bootstrap 3, how can I install bootstrap 4 instead.

The tutorials all say to just run "bower install bootstrap", but that just installs bootstrap 3 again.

Comment: Try https://github.com/bassjobsen/generator-bootstrap4; Yeoman generator to scaffold out a front-end Bootstrap 4 Web app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Bootstrap v4 alpha using bower?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156310/how-to-install-bootstrap-v4-alpha-using-bower)

Comment: other way around. this was posted before that one

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all remove old bootstrap from your project (remove `bower_components/bootstrap/` directory)

Than you have two options:

**1. Bower command with particular version:**

```
bower install bootstrap#4.0
```

**2. Using bower.json file**

create file called `bower.json` in your project root (see example below)

```
{
    "name": "app-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "4.0"
    }
}
```

then run

```
bower install
```

I'd recommend second option with bower.json file, because this is more flexible solution, you can use boser.json for other packages you need, by simple adding new line.

Answer (score 7):

Boostrap v4 is currently in an *alpha* state. The command `bower install bootstrap` installs the latest stable release.

To download the alpha version and save this choice run:

```
bower install bootstrap#4.0 --force-latest --save
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a right command line

> $ bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.3

there is official link how to manage bootstrap with other Package managers
[getbootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/)

Answer (score 0):

This also works for people using CodeKit (seems like you can't use bower commands in CodeKit)!

1) Delete the old *bower_components/bootstrap* folder.

2) Create a bower.json file in your root with this content:

```
{
"name": "app-name",
"version": "0.0.1",
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "4.0"
    }
}
```

3. Instrall regular *bootstrap* version via codekit.
--> Version 4.0-alpha will be installed automatically instead of the 3.x stable release.