# How to install Bootstrap v4 alpha using bower?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, bower-install, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

The [v4-alpha documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/) states

> Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha is available for download in several ways,
>   including some of your favorite package managers.

however, the mentioned

```
bower install bootstrap
```

installs the latest stable release 3.3.5 instead.

How to install v4 alpha using bower?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To install a specific version, append the GitHub tag using #:

```
bower install bootstrap#4.0.0-alpha
```

Comment: I get "no matches found: bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.2" when I try running this as of today. Anyone else seeing that? Add regular bootstrap and bumping the version # up to 4.0.0 in bower.json did the trick for me though.

Comment: @WillHitchcock: It still works for me. Also, this has been updated in the Bootstrap 4 docs and is currently the official way of installing the alpha version using bower. Are you sure you haven't got a typo in there somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Adding "bootstrap": "4.0" to the bower.json file under dependencies and running bower install in the terminal did it for me. Naturally, if you're using Yeoman and opt-in for the Bootstrap option, you'll want to remove the bootstrap folder under the bower_components folder.

Comment: I'm using Bower with ASP.net core 1.0 RC1 and also was successful adding `"bootstrap" : "4.0"` to the bower.json file to get the 4.0 Alpha 2. The Visual Studio tooling doesn't show it as a prerelease option, but did a nice restore after I added it manually.